# url rewriting mystery

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting, wamp

I have copied a project from a server to my local machine.

The site appears to be using **url rewriting**, so I have turned on `rewriting_module` in WAMP/Apache.

However, there is **no `.htaccess` file** in the project. Cannot figure out how the url rewritting is being achieved and so I can't make it work on my local machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your FTP client **show hidden files**

- If **not**, configure the client so it displays hidden files *—refer to your FTP client documentation—* and then copy it to your local machine
- If **it already does** or if you have copied the project with **SSH**, take a look at the remote apache configuration files (I'd look at virtual hosts) and compare with your local configuration.

*This is an example of how to configure CyberDuck FTP client :*

[image: Cyberduck]

Comment: It was indeed hidden, feel like a bit of a tit now but thanks for the help.

Comment: Happens to me all the time, no problem.

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess file is hidden file, make your folder view option to show hidden files.

OR

Is the project done in any frame work, that is codeigniter, zend or cake etc, in that case it will be having its own url structure in codeigniter url will be like this :  http://domain.com/controller/function